# Should I use CollectionView destructured or multiple image with Swift?

Tags: swift, image, swift3, uicollectionview

I would like to code this:

[image]

Because of the picture on the center, I really don't how I can do this.

My first choice was to create multiple image, but maybe I can do this with a CollectionView?

Comment: see: https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

Comment: you can use this library : https://github.com/zhxnlai/ZLBalancedFlowLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom `CollectionViewLayout` to your CollectionView. There you can define the appearance of `UICollectionViewCell` and `UICollectionReusableView`. You can use the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` [Delegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout) Functions to assign specific sizes from your `UICollectionViewController`

You can prepare your Layout (as the function says) in the `prepare()` function which you will need to override. Then you can get the attributes through the Layout [Methods](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout).

For small examples you can find many Tutorials where it is explained as @Scriptable already [commented](https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest)

Comment: Thank you ! I'll look at this :)